# Delete item in the database using a simple button on angular 7

Tags: html, angularjs-directive

im trying to create a delete button on one side of a word that i get from the data base and i cant figure out how to do it

I already delete the word but i have to use a input form on the html and i have to write by hand the word i that i want to delete, but this is no god for user experience, so thats why im seeking that X button

this is my html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">


            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Hashtags</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Hashtags <code> uno</code> agregar.</h6>
                <div class="row button-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4" *ngFor="let hash of getHashtag">
                      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onDelet(form.value)">


                        <button class="ti-close" type="submit"></button >
                        <input type="text" formControlName="hashtag" > {{hash}} <br>

                        <p id="competitors" > {{hash}}</p>


                      </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>


 <div class="card">
```

this is my componet file:

```
public onDelet(){

        this._getHashtag.deleteHashtag(this.form.value.hashtag).subscribe(

             result =>{

               // console.log(result)

                 this._getHashtag.getHashtag().subscribe(

          resultado =>{
          this.getHashtag = resultado

          this.getHashtag = this.getHashtag.result
         // console.log("Resultado", this.getHashtag)
          },

          error => {
        var mensajeError = <any>error;
            }
            );


            }

          )

  }
```

this is my service component:

```
deleteHashtag(hastagdel:string){

             let header = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"})
             return this._http.post(this.url + "/removeHashtags" ,{hashtags:[hastagdel]}, {withCredentials:true})

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to use `http.delete`, not `http.post` in your service.

`http.post` adds something to the db,

`http.delete` removes something,

`http.put` modifies something, and

`http.get` retrieves something from the db.

There are other http options, but those are the main ones.